# MySQL Slow Query Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database

Can you please help me to resolve the below slow query from MySQL?

```sql
SELECT `queue_message`.`topic_name`, `queue_message`.`body`, `queue_message_status`.`id` AS `relation_id`,
`queue_message_status`.`queue_id`,
`queue_message_status`.`message_id`, `queue_message_status`.`status`,
`queue_message_status`.`updated_at`, `queue_message_status.message_id`
INNER JOIN `queue` ON queue.id = queue_message_status.queue_id
WHERE (queue_message_status.status IN (2, 5))
  AND (queue.name = 'codegenerator')
ORDER BY `queue_message_status`.`updated_at` ASC,
  `queue_message_status`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: are you using message queues?

Comment: Please post complete TEXT A) query content and B) EXPLAIN SELECT sql_no_cache (rest of your query); for analysis.

Comment: @Nilesh-Patel  The posted query appears to be missing FROM.  A complete query would be helpful.  Could your post TEXT results of  A) EXPLAIN SELECT sql_no_cache (rest of your query); so we can see where indexes are missing?  AND B) SHOW CREATE TABLE queue; AND C) SHOW CREATE TABLE queue_message_status; AND D) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name like "queue"; AND E) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "queue_message_status"; for analysis.